Determining Primitive Element in the Ring?
Let the polynomial $ k(x) = x^3 + 2x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x] $ and
$ R = \mathbb{Z}_3[x] / (k(x)) $, the ring of equivalence classes in $ \mathbb{Z}_3[x] $ modulo
$ k(x) $. Determine whether $ [x] $ is a primitive element in $ R $?
Answer: Since $ k(x) $ is irreducible, $ R $ is a field with $ 3^3 = 27 $
elements. The multiplicative group has 26 elements. The possible orders for elements
in $ (R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot) $ are therefore 1, 2, 13, and 26. Let’s take powers of $ x $ and compute:
$$\begin{align*}
[x^3] &= [x + 2],\\
[x^6] &= [(x^3)^2] = [(x + 2)^2] = [x^2 + x + 1],\\
[x^{12}] &= [(x^2 + x + 1)^2] = [x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1] \\
&= 
[x(x + 2) + 2(x + 2) + 2x + 1] = [x^2 + 2],\\
[x^{13}] &= [x^{12} \cdot x] = [(x^2 + 2)x] = [x^3 + 2x]\\
 &= [x + 2 + 2x] = [2].
\end{align*}$$
Thus,
$$
[x^{26}] = [(x^{13})^2] = [2^2] = [1].
$$
We see that $x$ does not have order 1, 2, or 13, but has order 26. Therefore, it generates
the entire multiplicative group and is primitive.
My question
What do they mean by: The possible orders for elements are therefore 1, 2, 13, and 26."
I don't understand anything after that. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain to me.

The order of an element in a finite group always divides the order of the group. Everything after that is just calculation, using $[k]=0$ in $R$.

@anankElpis But how come the x^n=1 tell us that [x] is a primitive element in R? I mean the definition of primitive element is : "An element f in F is called a primitive element in F if it generates the entire multiplicative group, i.e., (F \ {0}, ·) = ".

If the order of $[x]$ is $26$, then all the $[x]^i$ for $i=0,\ldots,25$ are different, so $\langle[x]\rangle$ is the whole group.

@anankElpis and since the only potential orders are 1,2,13,26 and the actual sizeof the field is 26 and since x^26=1. We can conlude that. Btw do we really have to check x^n=1 n=1,2,13,26. Becuase in this case unless n=26 we know that x won't satisfie so can I not just check only that?

Checking that $\alpha^{26}=1$ does not imply that a smaller exponent wouldn't work. Consider for example $\alpha=[2x]$. You still have $\alpha^{26}=1$, but this time also $\alpha^{13}=1$, so $[2x]$ is not primitive. And checking $26$ is pointless because $\alpha^{26}=1$ for every non-zero element of $R$.
